# Java deleting an image from a panel

Tags: java, image, swing, graphics

I have been creating a Monopoly game, and while creating the graphical interface I added a panel in which an image is drawn for each bought territory.

Everything works well so far, but my problems started when I tried to delete the Image from the panel when I sell the territory.I have no Idea how to achieve that.

This is the code for the Image drawing when player 1 buys a territory:

```
if(property.Properties[i][0] == 1){
              if (y >= 390){
                  x = 140;
                  y = 40;
              }
             ImageIcon a = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("../Imagini/Headers/"  + headers[i] +".jpg"));
             icons = a.getImage();
             g.drawImage(icons, x, y, null);
             y +=25;

         }
```

The image should be erased when the position of the player is set to 0.

How can I erase the Image when I sell it?

Is there a method that does that?

If not can you suggest an alternative way for achieving this?

Comment: Try Graphics.fillRect() to clear image from the surface.

Comment: 1) `ImageIcon..`  Don't create one if you don't need it.  For the image, use `Image img = ImageIO.read(url);` 2) `g.drawImage(icons, x, y, null);`  Likely `this` is an `ImageObserver`, so use `this` instead of `null`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

put this [Icon/ImageIcon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) to the [JLabel#setIcon(myIcon)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html), and this/these `JLabel`(s) place by using [LayoutManger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) to the [JPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html),

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have Swing manage the object and give you an easy delete function, you could perhaps  use a layout manager to place the icon on a panel that is then placed on one of the frame's panes, and draw on the content pane if you need custom drawing.